# what it means for AIC NA in glmmPQL (MASS) summary output?

Tags: r

i'm new to glmmPQL.

```
   library(MASS)
    pql<-glmmPQL(fixed = sleeve~pain+stiff+diff,random = ~1|time,family = "binomial",data = knee)
```

when i run this model R give this warning "iteration 1", i don't know what it means

```
summary(pql)
```

```
 Data: knee 
  AIC BIC logLik
   NA  NA     NA
```

**what it means by NA in AIC,BIC and loglik?**

```
full result look like this

Linear mixed-effects model fit by maximum likelihood
 Data: knee 
  AIC BIC logLik
   NA  NA     NA

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | time
        (Intercept)  Residual
StdDev: 4.93377e-05 0.9880118

Variance function:
 Structure: fixed weights
 Formula: ~invwt 
Fixed effects: sleeve ~ pain + stiff + diff 
                 Value Std.Error DF    t-value p-value
(Intercept)  0.5775110 0.6854296 21  0.8425534  0.4090
pain        -0.0844256 0.1856925 21 -0.4546528  0.6540
stiff       -0.0152056 0.1430767 21 -0.1062757  0.9164
diff         0.0022752 0.0415744 21  0.0547254  0.9569
 Correlation: 
      (Intr) pain   stiff 
pain  -0.004              
stiff -0.275 -0.369       
diff  -0.134 -0.901  0.058

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
       Min         Q1        Med         Q3        Max 
-1.3181996 -0.8774770 -0.4111929  0.8923366  1.7722900 

Number of Observations: 27
Number of Groups: 3
```

Comment: Please create a [minimally working example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so that we may better understand the problem.

Comment: You need to calculate AIC, BIC etc using the likelihood of the model. glmmPQL is a quasi distribution model which does not return the likelihood. So nothing is wrong with AIC, BIC etc being NA.

Comment: Do you actually need the AIC?

Comment: not really need AIC, just want to know the meaning for that result because i see in some example the AIC give value result. i just want to make sure if there anything wrong with my model